# JSF selectManyCheckbox

Tags: jsf, seam

I'm having a hard time with a selectManyCheckbox.
Basically what I am doing is loading a List of Categories in a selectManyCheckbox type controller (have done this either with a List or with a List with convertEntity). My problem is with the selected elements (value="#{cardListProvider.categoriesHolder.selectedCategories}"). After some reading I understand it also has to be a List, but what kind? And how can I set the selected categories? I'm not saving them in DB but I need to run some action in the bean with them!

Here's what I have:

```
    <h:selectManyCheckbox id="supportCategoryCardFilter"
value="#{cardListProvider.categoriesHolder.selectedCategories}" styleClass="greyText" required="false" >

             <s:selectItems var="filterList" value="#{cardListProvider.categoriesList}" label="#{filterList.label}" />

             <a:support id="supportCategoryCardFilter2" event="onchange"
reRender="someHolder, categoriesPanel" eventsQueue="onchange" action="#{cardListProvider.findCards(cardListProvider.categoriesHolder.selectedCategories)}" />

    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

I have wasted several hours with this... Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind to a `String[]` array like so:

```
public class CheckSelector {
  private String[] chosen;

  public String[] getChosen() { return chosen; }
  public void setChosen(String[] chosen) { this.chosen = chosen; }

  public SelectItem[] getChoices() {
    return new SelectItem[] { new SelectItem("1"), new SelectItem("2"),
        new SelectItem("3") };
  }
}
```

The value of the `selectManyCheckbox` should be bound to `chosen`. Alternatively, you can use a `List`:

```
public class CheckSelector {
  private List<String> chosen;

  public List<String> getChosen() { return chosen; }

  public void setChosen(List<String> chosen) { this.chosen = chosen; }

  public List<SelectItem> getChoices() {
    return Arrays.asList(new SelectItem("1"), new SelectItem("2"),
        new SelectItem("3"));
  }
}
```

The exact rules for value support are listed in the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UISelectMany.html):

- If the component has an attached `Converter`, use it.
- If not, look for a `ValueExpression` for value (if any). The `ValueExpression` must point to something that is:

  - An array of primitives (such as `int[]`). Look up the registered by-class `Converter` for this primitive type.
  - An array of objects (such as `Integer[]` or `String[]`). Look up the registered by-class `Converter` for the underlying element type.
  - A `java.util.List`. Assume that the element type is `java.lang.String`, so no conversion is required.
- If for any reason a `Converter` cannot be found, assume the type to be a `String` array.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
The setter and getter you suggested is similar to what I am doing. I've tried it as a List<String> and tried other types as well but for some reason when I debug it, the list always comes empty... Can't figure this one out..

Comment: Have you added a `<h:messages />` control to the view to see if any controls are failing conversion/validation?

Comment: I got it to work. Honestly I cannot tell what the exact problem was! Thank you for your help! One more question please: the "chosen" is a List<String>; is it possible to use a List<Category> instead (possibly with a converter)? I think it would be better because being a List<String>, I am getting the id's of the selected categories in the list and then have to do operations to get the real Category. Thank you once again.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible by implementing a custom Converter: http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html But you'll just be moving the lookup operation to another part of your application - the browser is always going to send the server strings.

Comment: Thank you once again. I'll look that up! :)

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Seam so no need to use Strings or any primitive type, you can bind directly to List. You just have to add another tag inside your selectManyCheckbox component which is  and it will automatically do everything.

Better than doing all by yourself, check Seam documentation

http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/reference/en-US/html/controls.html#d0e28378